# javascript dependant drop down not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have searched through here to find a javascript drop down that changes based on another drop down and the code I have works in Chrome. However, it doesn't work in IE 8.0.6 and I was wondering if anyone could highlight the part that isn't working, or suggest another workaround (JQuery, CSS etc).

When I load this in IE, the second drop down is completely blank. The first drop down has a variation of the arrays, when a user selects one of those, they are then presented with the options in the array. So if I select iAffordability, i will be presented with the three values in the array.

Here is the code I am using

```
iAffordability = new Array("Unable to Get Mortgage", "Cant Afford to Move", "Price");
iDisintruction = new Array("Branch Disinstructed");
iCourtOrder = new Array("Court Order");
iLackofComms = new Array("Marketing", "Viewings", "Offers");
iLackofOffers = new Array("Not Happy with Amount", "Not Happy with Quality");

populateSelect();

$(function () {

    $('#WD').click(function () {
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect() {
    WD = $('#WD').val();
    $('#Sub').html();


    if (WD == 'iAffordability') {
        $('#Sub').empty();
        iAffordability.forEach(function (t) {

            $('#Sub').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

    if (WD == 'iDisintruction') {
        $('#Sub').empty();
        iDisintruction.forEach(function (t) {
            $('#Sub').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

    if (WD == 'iLackofComms') {
        $('#Sub').empty();
        iLackofComms.forEach(function (t) {
            $('#Sub').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

    if (WD == 'iLackofOffers') {
        $('#Sub').empty();
        iLackofOffers.forEach(function (t) {
            $('#Sub').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J8DS/5/)

UPDATE:

The code worked, I just had to add in:

```
if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};
```

to my existing JS.

Comment: it would be good if you can create a jsfiddle of your code..

Comment: Which IE? Note that *Array.prototype.forEach* is not supported in IE 8 and lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a refactoring and DRYing of your code:

```
var lists = {
    iAffordability: ["Unable to Get Mortgage", "Cant Afford to Move", "Price"],
    iDisintruction: ["Branch Disinstructed"],
    iCourtOrder: ["Court Order"],
    iLackofComms: ["Marketing", "Viewings", "Offers"],
    iLackofOffers: ["Not Happy with Amount", "Not Happy with Quality"]
};

$(function () {
    populateSelect();
    $('#WD').change(function () {
        populateSelect();
    });
});

function populateSelect() {
    var WD = $('#WD').val(), $sub = $('#Sub');
    $sub.empty();
    $.each(lists[WD] || ["Error"], function(_, t) {
        $sub.append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
    });
}
```

This should work even in older versions of IE because it uses the jQuery `$.each` function instead of `Array.prototype.forEach` - as RobG pointed out, this function was only added in IE9 (ah, if only IE forced itself to update like Chrome does...) and it should be much easier to expand in future.

Comment: you know the ".val()" does that take the "value" of the select? as the value in mine is what I want to upload to the SQL, but the html version is different and has spaces is as its user facing.

Thanks

Comment: @Greylegface `<option value="internalValue">User-facing Value</option>` might help you there.

Comment: I have added a JSfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5J8DS/7/), please could you have look please?Thank you

Comment: Yeah I have the value in the option like you said, but I was wondering which one the ".val" in the javascript looks at.

for example, one of them is

<option value="iAffordability" <?php echo FormFns::FormFill($aForm,'sReasonForWithdrawal','select','iAffordability');?>>Affordability</option>

Comment: The `value` attribute is the value. To get the "user-facing value" you need `text`.

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5J8DS/8/) - you had `<option val="...">` which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Niet. I have updated my code and tested it in Chrome, works fine. I tested it in IE8 and its not displaying the second drop down. The JSFiddle page doesnt even work in my IE!!

Should I look into some other coding to accomplish this?